# Greasemonkey Script to change drop down option if either of 2 options are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

So, I have a form that accepts values and on submit appends the values to another form in multiple tabs.

I'm trying to select the second option of a dropdown if the user chose IT or ES.

Here is my greasemonkey:

```
var taxcty = document.getElementById("CountryCode");
if (taxcty.options[taxcty.selectedIndex].value == 'IT' || 'ES'){

  (document.querySelector && document.querySelector('select[name="currentState"]') || []).value = 'Unverified';
}
```

So in theory, if the user selects IT or ES in the "CountryCode" field, I want the currentState field to change to "Unverified".

It's partially working right now but it is also changing all other country codes to Unverified lol. So if I chose "GB" it actually changes to Unverified but I only want it to do that for IT or ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (taxcty.options[taxcty.selectedIndex].value == 'IT' || taxcty.options[taxcty.selectedIndex].value == 'ES'){
```

You need to have both sides of the comparison for all values. 'ES' as a standalone operand will always be true as it is not null, empty or false.